# How is scribd html5?

Tags: html, scribd

I don't get it... how is Scribd html5 ?

In searching for an answer.. the closest I got against is found here:
http://loud.anotherquietday.com/post/598121586/scribds-html5-is-a-mess

Is there any reason for?

Comment: I think you didn't finish your thought in your question, and what does this have to do with programming?  You may want to relate this to a programming related question.

Comment: I guess in relation to programming, is there anything to be learnt from scribd in proclaiming that they have moved from 'flash to html5'? or is it just a marketing ploy in trying to use html5 as a buzzword ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scribd is actually using some HTML5-type features to replace old Flash functionality.  Web fonts, for instance (CSS3), are used to render the typography, and canvas is [used](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20004339-264.html) for drawing operations.  These are both in the HTML5 spec and are used extensively in Scribd.

Answer (score 0):

Scribd is using SoundManager 2. http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2